# We're the 25th most visited site on the network

Tags: discussion

I know this isn't a question, and barely a discussion topic, but I'd like to call out that we're the #25 site in terms of traffic on the network, sitting at 60k visits per day. When it comes to questions per day (an odd, but interesting stat) we're the number #12 site!

Where it gets really curious is that in terms of total users, we're down in position #51, which suggests all of us do more head-scratching than other communities out there, but also shows a good level of engagement.

I'm always impressed by this community, keep at it :)

If you want to dig in, the rankings are here: https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic

Comment: This should be a report that we can adjust. Like setting the timespan and showing some figures / graphs where we can see how good we are :D

Comment: @JohannesSchapdick people with 25K plus repuration can see that , run querries and create graphs.

Comment: Yeah, mods can access pretty detailed stats but aren't allowed to share them. I'm pretty sure the dataset is open though.

Comment: Looking only at sites that are focused on a specific technology, Salesforce is 4th.  (The top 3 are Unix & Linux, TeX - LaTeX, and Android Enthusiasts).

Comment: @PeterMortensen This isn't really a dupe since this came first and the other should be an answer here, but I think I'll mark it as such anyway since there's better discussion happening there.